# Code text editor snapping problem

Tags: code

Code text editor window does not snap. Every other app snaps. It doesn't matter if I use mouse or keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Code now snaps OK (at least in elementary Horus). I think it was due to the minimum window width being greater than half the screen width. If you are still having trouble try reducing the sidebar width or closing it altogether with `<Control>\`